# When does make practical sense to provide a confidence interval lower than 50%?

Tags: confidence-interval, reporting

I am reading the paper [Lorenz et al (2011)](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/22/9020.full), in which in relation to one diagram it is stated "error-bars represent 10% confidence intervals".

[image: Lorenz et al (2011), p9023]

I understand that the idea of a 10% confidence interval makes theoretical sense. I'm leaving aside the question of whether in the paper I'm reading the "10%" is a typo, and also the question of whether it makes sense in this particular context.

Instead, what I'm wondering is whether there are *any* contexts in which it makes practical sense to provide a low (< 50%) confidence interval, instead of a higher one (e.g. 95%, 80%). In what circumstances would doing this be a good idea?

**References**

1. Lorenz, J., Rauhut, H., Schweitzer, F., & Helbing, D. (2011). How social influence can undermine the wisdom of crowd effect. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 108(22), 9020-9025.

Comment: Interesting. I'm hard pressed to come up with a particularly good use for an interval where a large proportion of the time you use it, doesn't contain the quantity you're interested in. If you think of it more as a 'slightly smeared' point estimate, maybe there's some value.

Comment: I realize its not part of your question, but judging from some other clumsy phrasing in the article (where what was said may have been not quite correct but where the intent is easily inferred in context), I'd be inclined to assume they meant 90% intervals. Certainly if they were really to use 10% intervals, it would require some kind of comment as to *why*; the absence of such comment reinforces my feeling that it's merely clumsy/misleading phrasing. One assumes the referees include nobody with enough statistical knowledge to insist they either fix it or explain why 10% intervals are used

Comment: If these really were 10% intervals, then the 90 or 95% intervals would be enormously wider and it's hard to see that there is any pattern in the results.

Comment: @Nick Cox is correct.  From the [full diagram](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/22/9020/F1.large.jpg), especially the numerical values for the "exemplary session" in figure C, it is clear these are not 10% intervals.

Comment: While we are taking potshots at this, in PNAS of all places, note the occurrence of red, green and blue curves (or in the case of some of us, know that the three curves are in red, green and blue). The point symbols in each panel are identical for the three curves, so that doesn't help those who have difficulties with red and green.

Comment: I frequently encounter references to the 95% or 99% significance level, and so forth. See e.g. my review at https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2J3BB34GY0JHI This is thus the complementary [sic] error.